# Upload de imagem com Spring e UIkit

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Prezados implementando upload no meu projeto, me orientei pelo projeto da Algaworks Brewer ( faz o upload da foto da cerveja), utilizando um framework front-end [UIkit](http://www.getuikit.com)
O upload esta sendo feito, pelo que pude perceber que em uma pasta com o nome "null" esta servindo como local onde esta sendo armazenado os arquivos, mais tem algo bem estranho ocorrendo e eu não sei dizer o motivo.

Bem primeiro a imagem do arquivo que foi feito upload não esta aparecendo e percebo o erro 404 esta ocorrendo em um GET, segundo observei que é criado uma pasta dentro da pasta do projeto só que com o nome null, quando deveria ser a pasta foto

Entendo que não seja muito elucidativo o que descrevi mais se alguém que faz uso destas tecnologias puder comentar

O projeto faz uso do SpingBoot, Thymeleaf e Bootstrap[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Também passei por este problema, quando da 404 é que o spring não está encontrando o caminho da pasta para salvar a foto, verifique se realmente o app criou a pasta dentro do `projeto project/.null/nomePasta`.
Te aconselho você fazer diferente ao invés de criar o a pasta dentro projeto você pode criar ela fora do projeto, pois, você vai provavelmente vai compilar o projeto e executar no *tomcat*, quando compilado ele gera um `project.war` onde estão os arquivos compilados do app.

Segue um exemplo que usei na minha app para criar a pasta fotos fora do app:

```
@Profile("local")
@Component
public class LogoPath {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogoPath.class);

private Path local;

public static Path getDefaultPath() {
    //Servidor linux
    Path pathDefault = Paths.get("/app/fotos");
    if(Files.notExists(pathDefault, LinkOption.NOFOLLOW_LINKS)) {
        //No usuario do windows
        String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
        pathDefault = Paths.get(userHome, "fotos");
    }
    return pathDefault;
}

public LogoPath() {
    this(getDefaultPath());
}

public LogoPath(Path path) {
    this.local = path;
    criarPastas();
}

private void criarPastas() {
    try {
        Files.createDirectories(this.local);

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Pasta criada para salvar arquivos.");
            logger.debug("Pasta default: " + this.local.toAbsolutePath());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Erro criando pasta para salvar arquivos.", e);
    }

}

}
```